# How to wait for Direction Service to complete to access Direction property of Direction Display

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing my work with `Google Map API`. To draw a route between two points, I use this function:

```
function calcRoute(start, end) {
        var pStart = new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat(), start.lng());
        var pEnd = new google.maps.LatLng(end.lat(), end.lng());

        var request = {
            origin: pStart,
            destination: pEnd,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

                // Box the overview path of the first route
                var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                boxes = rboxer.box(path, distance);

                //drawBoxes(boxes);
                nearbyMarkets = search_market(boxes);
                // PUT HERE???
            }
        });
    }
```

After this, I need access the `Direction Display` object, which only available after the route is rendered successfully (means this function's done). I tried to put that code block in that position, but at that time, the `Direction property` of `Direction Display` is still not available, so it's failed. But if I call it after `calcRoute` function, it's OK.

So, my question is, how can I know when the callback finish so that I can continue my work? I've tried putting a `flag` like below, but it was unsuccessful, the loop is infinite.

```
function calcRoute(start, end) {
        var pStart = new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat(), start.lng());
        var pEnd = new google.maps.LatLng(end.lat(), end.lng());
        var pass = false;

        var request = {
            origin: pStart,
            destination: pEnd,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

                // Box the overview path of the first route
                var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                boxes = rboxer.box(path, distance);

                //drawBoxes(boxes);
                nearbyMarkets = search_market(boxes);
                pass = true;
            }
        });
        while (!pass) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: The DirectionsRenderer is always accessible when it has been initialized(no matter if there has been drawn a direction or not). Please explain what exactly didn't work as expected.

Comment: I tried to access `directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0]`, but `directionsDisplay.directions` is not available, maybe null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the `directions_changed`-event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',function(){
 if(this.get('directions')){
   //directions are available, do something
 }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks a lot :) Are you from Google developer team?